# how to divide dataset into train and test set?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, classification, data-mining

i am tried to classify dataset using naive Bayes classification algorithm with map-reduce framework.
my question is how to divide dataset into training and testing set to calculate accuracy from corrected and incorrect-ed classified instances?

Comment: Have you considered using random sampling?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RemovePercentage` filter
training set:
1. Load the full dataset
2. select the RemovePercentage filter in the preprocess panel
3. set the correct percentage for the split
4. apply the filter
5. save the generated data as a new file

test set:
1. Load the full dataset (or just use undo to revert the changes to the dataset)
2. select the RemovePercentage filter if not yet selected
3. set the invertSelection property to true
4. apply the filter
5. save the generated data as new file

Comment: dataset is about 1 giga and weka don't supply big data 
any help?

Comment: @medooSa  I will recommend R programming and if you want a GUI interface, nothing better than RStudio. A good online resource for learning R is R-bloggers. However, compared to a PCA or k-means... if you do the same in R it takes less than 5 minutes. (I have tested this in terms of efficiency)

Apart from R, your other alternatives is RapidMiner or Apache Hadhoop... however in my opinion weka is the best for bigdata... I propose you have a look on gate [LINK](https://gate.ac.uk/)

Comment: i have written  a compiled java .jar file using eclipse . is this allowed for R programming to import .jar file and work on it or i should write all code using R programming ?

Comment: @medooSa you'd have to include it using an R package make your structure something like   
 `inst
 java
  jarFileHere.jar 
R
 r_code_file.R`                                                                                           Also take a look at  [Deducer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Deducer/index.html)  and [DeducerplugInExample](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DeducerPlugInExample/index.html). There is a tutorial on including java code in your package available on Deducer's web manual: http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Development#suaptijc

Comment: yes i will read it and try ...thanks for all and your effort :D

Comment: @medooSa have you looked at weka 3 for mining big data? I'd give it a look before attacking R. [Weka3](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/bigdata.html) good luck my dude :^) Hope ive answered your question

Comment: i don't know about weka big data befor. i tried to load big data into weka and platform stopped . kindelly another question, is it possible to upload my classification model into weka and output result or it must be the weka classifier? thnx bro you help me alot and answer alot of questions really thank you :D <3

Comment: @medooSa You save a trained classifier with the `-d` like `java weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -C 0.25 -M 2 -t /some/where/train.arff -d /other/place/j48.model` And you can load it with `-l` and use it on a test set like `java weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -l /other/place/j48.model -T /some/where/test.arff` however im not entirely sure that answers your question and i wouldn't want to give you wrong information id reference you to [Save Model & Load Model](http://machinelearningmastery.com/save-machine-learning-model-make-predictions-weka/) im not entirely sure if it has to be a weka classifier :^/